# looking for code that produces a Clustered Affinity Matrix used in database vertical partitioning

Tags: database, algorithm, distributed-database

Before I spend time writing it myself, does anyone have pointers to implementations (in any language but Python, Java, C, C++ would be preferred) of algorithms that are used in database vertical partitioning?  Specifically, I'm looking for code that can generate a [clustered affinity matrix](http://books.google.com/books?id=kRZwykrabCQC&lpg=PA53&dq=%22Clustered%20Affinity%20Matrix%22&pg=PA53#v=onepage&q=%22Clustered%20Affinity%20Matrix%22&f=false) given an Atrribute Affinity Matrix.